# How do I return this JSON in django without it being escaped?

Tags: python, json, django, pandas

In my Django project, I am trying to return a `JsonResponse` but the data being returned is being escaped 'somewhere'. When I run the code through Jupyter Notebook I don't have a problem. My DataFrame structure is:

[image: DataFrame Structure]

---

My Django response reads in my DataFrame pickle and processes it like this:

```
def API_FTEs_month(request, storeCode):
    df1=pd.read_pickle(storeCode+'.pickle')
    result=(df1.groupby(['Date','Job Role'], as_index=False)
        .apply(lambda i: i[['Department', 'Team', 'Days']].to_dict('r'))
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={0: 'Assignments'})
         .to_json(orient='records'))
return JsonResponse(result, safe=False)
```

I'm not sure why, but the response gets escaped like this:

```
"[{\"Date\":\"2017-12-31\",\"Job Role\":\"Junior\",\"Assignments\":[{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"A\",\"Days\":12.8311126233},{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"B\",\"Days\":9.7797036952},{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"C\",\"Days\":12.4532628859},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"A\",\"Days\":13.2005991473},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"B\",\"Days\":11.2217690247},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"C\",\"Days\":9.9799650502}]},{\"Date\":\"2017-12-31\",\"Job Role\":\"Senior\",\"Assignments\":[{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"A\",\"Days\":12.3088204188},{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"B\",\"Days\":11.6027520428},{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"C\",\"Days\":8.4242249342},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"A\",\"Days\":10.2680664459},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"B\",\"Days\":10.7355819544},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"C\",\"Days\":14.4751405746}]},{\"Date\":\"2018-01-31\",\"Job Role\":\"Junior\",\"Assignments\":[{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"A\",\"Days\":9.8390990646},{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"B\",\"Days\":7.8840336082},{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"C\",\"Days\":7.4098884623},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"A\",\"Days\":6.5804561812},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"B\",\"Days\":7.9109739164},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"C\",\"Days\":7.6766255979}]},{\"Date\":\"2018-01-31\",\"Job Role\":\"Senior\",\"Assignments\":[{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"A\",\"Days\":5.9779944185},{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"B\",\"Days\":7.8300778676},{\"Department\":\"Electronics\",\"Team\":\"C\",\"Days\":7.9050436379},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"A\",\"Days\":6.9225874658},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"B\",\"Days\":7.6001780124},{\"Department\":\"Household\",\"Team\":\"C\",\"Days\":6.5897367619}]}]"
```

---

Recreating the attempt in Jupyter Notebook I seem to get valid JSON:

**Notebook:**
[image: Jupyter Notebook]

I was assuming it's something in my `to_json()` or `JsonResponse` that is the problem but I have tried inserting other JSON attempts into my `JsonResponse` such as the following which gives me valid JSON (but not the required structure) without escaping:

```
def nested_dict():
    return collections.defaultdict(nested_dict)
result=nested_dict()

for row in df4.itertuples():
    result[row.Index[0]][row.Index[1]][row[1]][row[2]]['sales'] = row.Days

json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: If change `to_json` to `to_dict`, how does it work?

Comment: The `JsonResponse` expects a Python object that will then be JSON encoded. You are passsing in JSON already, resulting in JSON encoded JSON.

Comment: D'oh! Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
.to_json(orient='records')
```

to [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
.to_dict(orient='records')
```

in order to prevent double encoded **json**.

This is better explained in the comment from [Klaus D.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442363/how-do-i-return-this-json-in-django-without-it-being-escaped/46442506#comment79840874_46442363):

> The **JsonResponse** expects a **Python** object that will then be **JSON** encoded. You are passsing in **JSON** already, resulting in **JSON** encoded **JSON**.